# I am not able to load image and name of the category on the screen using Firebase as the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fragment

I am unable to load the names and images of each category on screen. I have tried different ways to load them up but no luck.

I am using a fragment to display the categories.

I have got the same error messages [image: image1] when I run the app even when I use those different ways of loading the image and name on the emulator.

The database structure looks like this DB Sample [image: image2].

This is the **CategoryFragment.java** file

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

View myFragment;

RecyclerView categoryList;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder> adapter;

// Firebase Tings
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference categories;

public static CategoryFragment newInstance() {
    CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
    return categoryFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    categories = database.getReference().child("Category");

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
    categoryList = (RecyclerView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.categoryList);
    categoryList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
    categoryList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadCategories();

    return myFragment;
}

private void loadCategories() {
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder>(
            Category.class,
            R.layout.category_item,
            CategoryViewHolder.class,
            categories
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, final Category model, int position) {
            viewHolder.tvCategoryName.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.ivCategoryImage);

            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.format("%s | %s", adapter.getRef(position).getKey(), model.getName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    categoryList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

I have used these following ways to display the categories w/ their images

**1.**

```
categories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://quizmate-5be87.firebaseio.com/").child("Category");
```

**2.**

```
categories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
```

**3.**

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
categories = database.getReference().child("Category");
```

The third way is already being used

**Category.java - model class**

```
public class Category {

private String name, image;

public Category() {
}

public Category(String name, String image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

This is what is showing when I run the [image: image3].

Thank you in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name and image fields in your Firebase `JSON` start with an uppercase letter(Name, Image). The `getImage(`) corresponds to a property called `image` not `Image`.
One way to correct it is to have your variables match the case with those in `Firebase`.